# Silverlight, update gui by changing img source c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-interface

I'm trying to make a binary clock, an it works fine.

It works like this.

Every time you call a method called run, it sets the time, and change some img source (the img is my lamp, change img source every time it shut off or on).

But how can I get it to run all the time?

If I make a loop it won't start on my mobile, and it's like using threading does do anything.

Is there a method for update the gui after you change some properties?

XMAL Code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="BinSample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,187,0,0" Name="imag1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Source="/BinSample;component/img/knapSluk.png" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //test one
        //try to make a neverending loop
        Run();

        //testc two
        //try loop with thread an sleep funtion.
        thredRun();


    }

    public void thredRun()
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(thredRun));
        while (true)
        {
            Run();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            if (hour % 10 == 0)
                imag1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/knapTaand.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                imag1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/knapSluk.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have working so far and of the loop that doesn't work?

Comment: @SilverSolver I can zip my projct and upload it if you want,

else its something like this

'while(ture)
{
  if(statemant is true)
  img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/knapSluk.png", UriKind.Relative));
  else
  imgHour1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/knapTaand.png", UriKind.Relative));
}'

Comment: btw, first time posting anything here on stackoverflow, so i kinda don't really now every thing like how to past a part of your code.

Comment: It is less helpful to post the entire project, we just need the bits relevant to your problem. As for formatting try here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @SilverSolver here is a example one my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First you are not using the Thread class correctly, [check this tutorial to get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Even when you do correct your usage of the Thread class, you are either going to end up blocking the UI Thread, or you will end up with a Cross-Thread exception.

In this case, perhaps the easiest way for you to achieve what you want is to use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1) };
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    SetImageSource();
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetImageSource();
}

void SetImageSource()
{
    int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    if (hour % 10 == 0)
        imag1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/knapTaand.png", UriKind.Relative));
    else
        imag1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/knapSluk.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: when i try it my img didn't show up,
if i wanna upload the new code i got, am i to do that in a ansawer or edit the main post?

Comment: wait, i think i got it working.
, yes it's working. Thx a lot mate!